# method names with fluent interface

Tags: java, scala, naming, fluent-interface

I have a `Permissions` class in Java with methods in fluent style like this:

```
somePermissions.setRead(true).setWrite(false).setExecute(true)
```

The question is, whether I should name these methods `set{Property}` or only `{property}`. The latter would look like this:

```
somePermissions.read(true).write(false).execute(true)
```

If I look at these methods separately I would expect that `read` reads something, but on the other hand it is closer to the intention to have something like named paramaters like in Scala:

```
Permission(read=true, write=false, execute=true)
```

Comment: Silly question, but why not just use named and default parameters? It's both the tersest and the most readable, at least for the examples you've given.

Comment: I should have said that I use Java, which doesn't support named and default parameters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`set{Property}` is better than just {property} for conveying intent.  However since your examples are simple boolean properties, an even better fluent interfance might be:

```
somePermissions.AllowRead().DenyWrite().AllowExecute();
```

Comment: That's fine, but you8 should think about handling the case where someone chains nonsensically: `AllowRead().DenyRead()`

Comment: @oxbow_lakes Why? Would be (e.g.) smoking OK for you if you first allowed it and *then* forbade? IMHO that's perfectly clear (although you may want to prevent such cases because they might by made by mistake).

Answer (score 6):

This is a classic problem with fluent interfaces. While I agree with @Bozho that setRead() is more self explanatory, the objective in fluent interfaces is to make the whole "sentence" readable as opposed to making individual method calls readable.

Thus, I would go a step further. How about:

```
somePermissions.readable().nonWritable().executable()
```

See also Martin Fowler's [post](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html) about this topic. He says: "Building a fluent API like this leads to some unusual API habit"

Answer (score 5):

`set{Property}` definitely. It tells what the method is doing. Imagine your property is called `visible` or `encoding` or `algorithm`. Not using `set` won't make any sense.

You can use more descriptive action names, which differ from the name of the property. For example:

`visible` -> `show(..)`
`encoding` -> `encode(..)`
`read` > `makeReadable(..)`
`name` -> `giveName(..)` ("name" is a verb, but is ambiguous)

Answer (score 1):

The `set` clearly interferes with clarity. They aren't really beans-like method, so I say drop it.

I would also suggest separating the builder from the product. Prefer immutability in the product.

If you have flags, I think it much better to use booleans rather than pairs of methods. The Java library made this change going from 1.0 to 1.1. However, I still don't like booleans. There is not much higher-level meaning in `true` and `false`. `enum`s are better. Better yet, if you are talking about something which can be considered a set (as in the example), then use `Set` (probably implemented as `EnumSet`).